# Ubuntu 13.10 Slow Booting

Tags: boot, 13.10

I installed Ubuntu 1 day ago. It has very slow booting. Booting takes 2-3 minutes.
I have `bootchart` logs but have no idea how fix it.

Ubuntu 13.10 with Gnome-shell(gdm)
CPU: AMD A10-4600M
RAM: 8GB

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could be running out of room, or have too much installed. Try slimming the fat - maybe some `sudo apt-get autoremove`? If not, get your data out and reinstall.

Comment: autoremove has 1 package... Installed soft for work lamp/IDE/skype/pidgin and other, nothing unusual. It's just been installed, why reinstall :(

Comment: I found the reason for the long booting - fglrx-updates(or fglrx). With open source x.org drivers booting has normal speed. But has low fps...

Answer (score 0):

Try to append `libata.force=1:noncq` into `/etc/default/grub`, like the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=1:noncq"
```

Then:

```
sudo update-grub
```